# apply my function if...else statement with condition doesn't pass

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

my input(as example):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'frame':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],'sum_result_ICV':[0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0], 'sum_result_AO':[0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]})
dd['result_ICV'] = 0
dd['result_ATO'] = 0
```

My code and my_func:

```
for z in range(0,len(cv_details)):
            def result_func(row):
                for i in range(0,len(dd)):
                    if row==2:
                        return(cv_details[z])
                    elif row==1:
                        if dd.loc[dd['sum_result_'+cv_details[z]]==2,'frame'].empty:
                            return ('ReviewNG-'+cv_details[z])
                        elif (dd['frame'][i]-dd.loc[dd.iloc[:,z+1]==2,'frame'].iloc[0]) <=3 :
                            return('NG-'+cv_details[z])                                
                        elif (dd['frame'][i]-dd.loc[dd.iloc[:,z+1]==2,'frame'].iloc[-1]) <=3 :  
                             return('NG-'+cv_details[z]) 
                        else:
                             return('ReviewNG-'+cv_details[z])
                    elif row==0:
                        return('Other')
                    else:
                        return ""
            dd.iloc[:,z+3]=dd.iloc[:,z+1].apply(result_func)
```

I expect:
[image]

But my output:

[image]

So as you can see: I need some condition, for example: "if `sum_result_ICV` equal 0 -> put "Other", if 'sum_result_ICV' equal 1 AND difference of (Number of `Frame` minus Number where first/last `Frame`==2) equal or less than 3 -> put "NG-ICV" in other wise "ReviewNG-ICV"(for example number of `frame` 11 where in `sum_result_ICV` was 1 and in distance from number 7 of `frame` where was `sum_result_ICV` equal 2, so 11-7>3 put "ReviewNG-ICV" ). In my example `frame` from 1 to 3 must be "NG-ICV", and also from 8 to 10. But from 11 to 14 it must be "ReviewBG-ICV". Also, please see pic that I expect from my function.  So what I do wrong?

**UPDATE** based an answer of @woblob

That new code with loop:

```
for z in range(0,len(cv_details)):
    df.iloc[df.iloc[:,z+1].to_numpy()==0, z+2 ] = 'Other'
    mask2= df.iloc[:,z+1]==2
    mask1 =df.iloc[:,z+1]==1
    df.iloc[mask2,z+2]=cv_details[z]
    if df.loc[mask2,'frame'].empty:
        df.iloc[mask1,z+2]='ReviewNG-'+cv_details[z]
    else:
        df_frame_first=df.loc[mask2,'frame'].iloc[0]
        df_frame_last=df.loc[mask2,'frame'] .iloc[-1]  
        mask_lt_3 = ((df.frame - df_frame_first) <= 3) | (df.frame - df_frame_last <= 3)
        ones_lt_3 = mask1 & mask_lt_3
        ones_not_lt_3 = mask1 & (~mask_lt_3)
        df.iloc[ones_lt_3, z+2] = 'NG-'+cv_details[z]
        df.iloc[ones_not_lt_3 , z+2] = 'ReviewNG-'+cv_details[z]
```

Comment: q: "So what I do wrong?"
a: You wrote a function that compares single values of each rows with values from the entire df.
This is not how you work with `pandas dataframe`.
Conditions on `dataframe` should be written with `.loc[condition/s, column_effected] = output` and not with self made functions and loops.

Comment: It seems that the loop `for i in range(0,len(dd)):` is not useful and `i==0` always, because the loop breaks at any `return`.

Comment: It's `row==0` not `i==0` @АлексейР

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your condition for 1. Why should 8,9, 10 be 'NG-ICV'?

Comment: @HenryEcker I meant that the `if (dd['frame'][i]...`) condition uses `i`, which is always `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was trying to untangle the logic, I reworked it completely.

```py
dd.loc[dd.result == 0, "sum_result"] = 'Other'
mask2 = dd.result == 2 
mask1 = dd.result == 1
dd.loc[mask2, "sum_result"] = 'ICV'
if dd.loc[mask2,'frame'].empty:
    dd.loc[mask1, "sum_result"] = 'No sum_result==2'
else:
    dd_frame_first = dd.loc[mask2,'frame'].iloc[0]
    dd_frame_last = dd.loc[mask2,'frame'].iloc[-1]    
    mask_lt_3 = ((dd.frame - dd_frame_first) <= 3) | (dd.frame - dd_frame_last <= 3)
    ones_lt_3 = mask1 & mask_lt_3
    ones_not_lt_3 = mask1 & (~mask_lt_3)
    dd.loc[ones_lt_3, "sum_result"] = 'NG-ICV'
    dd.loc[ones_not_lt_3 , "sum_result"] = 'ReviewNG-ICV'
```

Comment: yeap, you way is work, but I  have one issue: I need run this function in other loop for multi-column and label. Let's say my dd have more than one column with "result" and i need run in each column that logic

Comment: then modify your sample data and expected output so it represents your real data better, and I will try to answer.

Comment: edit  for more represent my issue, thanks